# Understanding CanCan initialize method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, rails-admin

I'm having a hard time understanding how CanCan works. I have the following model

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user && user.email == "jason@gmail.com"
      can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
      can :dashboard                  # allow access to dashboard
    end
  end
end
```

When it comes to my rails_admin file in the `initializers` folder

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :cancan

  config.main_app_name = ['Pr', 'Admin']

  config.current_user_method { } # auto-generated
end
```

I want to have one user to access the admins dashboard with the email "jason@gmail.com", but how does CanCan know who is currently signed in at the time? Does it rely on a helper method I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CanCan uses a `current_ability` method to supply the ability, [and in that it uses `current_user`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/ff2b632f1524bac4273fe113968d73ea62114652/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L357).  I know at least Devise has this method, other auth frameworks must commonly supply it too, not sure.

Comment: I have a `UserSessionsHelper` module with the `current_user` method to handle currently logged in users. I guess I don't need to worry about anything else then.